# Best way to estimate number of 'active' cell phones nearby

Tags: rf, radio, gsm, cellphone, microwave

I work in a place where we're very interested in ways to measure occupancy, one way being to extrapolate this data from an estimate of the number of cell phones near to a fixed point.

How does one measure the number of nearby 'active' cell phones; 'active' meaning they are transmitting data over a cellular network (3G, 4G, LTE, etc.).

Is there some way of tuning an RF receiver and then measuring the volume of traffic within that frequency band?  I assume that it can't be done easily via 'analog' means, e.g. with just an aerial and a spectrum analyser?

How else could we passively estimate the number of nearby active cell phones?

Footnote: We wouldn't need to capture, or decrypt, any of the data, this is not a snooping exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For radio systems with a 'duplex offset', that is a different frequency band for downlink and uplink, a crude estimate *can* be done with an aerial and spectrum analyser. Tune the spectrum analyser to the uplink band, and use some proxy like the total power, or the number of data packets that start and stop. You might calibrate this proxy by loading the network with a few phones of your own at 5am when there's little other traffic.